# Regarding Long distance wireless communication

Tags: wireless

I have a requirement to transmit some sensor data through wireless to a distance of 2 kilometers. I am a newbie to these technologies and concepts. Can anyone help me by providing some pointers to start with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a question for the Electronics Stack Exchange.

- ["Long distance wireless communication"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/75325/long-distance-wireless-communication)
- ["Long distance communication"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/113188/long-distance-communication)
- ["Wireless communication over long distances"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/wireless-communication-over-long-distances)
- ["Zigbee communication outdoors at long distance ( around 1 - 1.5 km)"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102408/zigbee-communication-outdoors-at-long-distance-around-1-1-5-km)